# Verbreitung des Selbst-Reflexiven Pronomens

Tags: idiom, dialect, reflexive, reference-request

Stimmt es, dass in südlichen Dialekten die Verwendung des Pronomens *sich* nach einigen Verben, die im Hochdeutsch bzw. in meinem Idiolekt nicht selbst-reflexiv sind, zumindest in festen Wendungen üblich ist?

Das Beispiel, das ich gerade im Kopf habe, lässt sich leider schwer suchen, da das betreffende Verb in anderen Konstellationen tatsächlich selbst-reflexiv ist, dann aber immer mit abtrennbarer Vorsilbe.

Ich will vorerst kein mutmaßliches Beispiel anführen, um keine mutmaßenden Antworten zu provozieren. Ich hoffe, es gut umschreiben zu können.

Die Frage wurmt mich seit ich vom [Medium](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Medium) ([Mediopassiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(Grammatik))) gelesen habe, dass dieser in bestimmten Sprachen durch selbst-reflexive Konstruktionen ersetzt wurde. Später stellte sich dann raus, dass *middle-voice* für Latein zumindest keine klar definierte Kategorie bezeichnet, sondern verschiedentlich im Schrifttum verwendet wird -- eben eigentlich nicht vorhanden. Nur Alt-Griechisch führt *middle-voice* als eigenes Konjugations-Schema.<sup>1</sup> Slavisch wiederum hat Selbstreflexion ins Konjugationsschema eingebaut.<sup>2, 3</sup>

Es versteht sich von selbst, dass die Situation im Deutschen ähnlich aussieht.

@DavidVogt bietet einen [kurzen Überblick reflexiver Verben](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55220/reflexive-verbs-confusion-definition/55221#55221)

> ... Secondly, there are verbs that are truly reflexive (echt or obligatorisch reflexiv in German). They are distinguished by the fact that they have a semantically empty syntactic argument, i.e. one which is not linked to a semantic argument.
>
> **beeilen**
>
> ... The object has to be coreferent with the subject – reflexive – i.e. in the third person, it must be *sich*. ...

Ob Ausdrücke die häufig mit der 3. Person verwendet werden, insbesondere indefinite Neutra, eine Untergruppe bilden steht da leider nicht. Vermutlich ist es nur schwer abzugrenzen. *Das verläuft sich irgendwann*, wie man so sagt.

Ich frage also, ob archaische Elemente in diesem Sinne in Dialekten beobachtet werden können, die anderswo nicht obligatorisch selbst-reflexiv sind.

Der Titel der Frage, "Verbreitung ..." ist etwas hochgestochen. Ein Verweis auf Studien zum Thema wäre super. Ein einfaches Beispiel für bestimmte typische Wendungen würde mir aber schon ausreichen.

---

1: siehe dazu bspw. https://german.stackexchange.com/a/54386 dort auch die Behauptung, *oft* werden unterschiedliche Verben verwendet (dazu fällt mir ein: *hing* vs *hang*).

2: @ChristianGeiselmann über Bulgarisch https://german.stackexchange.com/a/55207

Ein Verb für *lernen* und *lehren* im Polnischen, viz *uczę* https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34213/distribution-and-origin-of-reflexive-pronouns-like-myself-across-languages

3: Eine ähnliche Frage zu s-suffix im Skandinavischen, viz *lera*, blieb soweit unbeantwortet https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34647/origin-of-s-verbs-in-norwegian-and-swedish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohne die Frage richtig verstanden zu haben nehme ich dennoch an, dass es etwas mit dem zu tun hat, was ich in der Bairischen Grammatik von Ludwig Merkle zu lesen steht (*Ludwig Merkle, Bairische Grammatik, M 1990, S. 134 f.*:

[image]

Das nur für den Fall, dass es noch nicht bekannt ist.

Comment: "*Dengga Sa si nix!* oder besser: *Dengga S' eahna nix!*", "*Dea scheißd si nix.", goldig, danke! Sieht mir danach aus, als ob *Sa si* zu *S'* zusammengezogen und *eahna* "ihnen" zum Ausgleich eingefügt wurde. Mysteriös.