# 1 Verb, 2 past participles. Is there a difference between the participles?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, verb

Some German verbes seem to have two different past participles.

e.g. hängen -> gehangen/gehängt

Can you choose whichever you want or is there any difference in meaning, application or regional use?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7510

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, we have two slightly different verbs with different grammar here. One verb is *hängen* and is intransitive, the other is *etwas (an einen Ort) hängen* and transitive.

---

The intransitive verb is *always* conjugated as *hängen – hing – gehangen.* It means *to hang somewhere* in the way that e.g. a coat is hanging on a hanger or a picture is hanging on the wall.

> Die Jacke hängt am Haken. → Die Jacke hing am Haken. → Die Jacke ist am Haken gehangen.
>
> Das Bild hängt schief. → Das Bild hing schief. → Das Bild ist schief gehangen.<sup>[1]</sup>

Note that the place does not have to be specificied but that there is often an additional specifier present. If the place is specified with a *Wechselpräposition,* the noun following it is in dative case to signify a state.

---

The transitive verb is *always* conjugated as *hängen – hängte – gehängt.* It means *to hang up something,* i.e. it describes the process that leads to intransitive *hängen.* Therefore, it often turns up as *aufhängen* rather than pure *hängen.*

> Ich hänge das Bild an die Wand. → Ich hängte das Bild an die Wand. → Ich habe das Bild an die Wand gehängt.
>
> Ich hänge meine Jacke auf. → Ich hängte meine Jacke auf. → Ich habe meine Jacke aufgehängt.

Note that if the place is specified with a *Wechselpräposition,* the following noun is in accusative case to signify a movement towards there (of the object).

---

[1]: A number of verbs that use *haben* in perfect tense in northern Germany use *sein* in the South, Austria, South Tyrol and probably also Switzerland. Being from Bavaria, I use the southern-typical *sein.*

Comment: I was taught that both participles need the auxiliary "haben", yet you use once "sein", once "haben". Can you explain this to me?

Comment: @Kristina Haha, I didn’t even realise that. But a note has been added.

Comment: @Kristina the verbs  that in the southern regions use 

> sein

 instead of 

> haben

 are all ***intransitive verbs that have the meaning of a static position***, such as "sitzen; stehen; liegen" and "hängen"